# What is the principle of multiplication of D-normalized polynomials for a CRC calculation?

Tags: crc

I'm studying the principle of CRCs from [*everything we know about CRC but afraid to forget*](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/doc/crc-doc.1.0.pdf) by Andrew Kadatch1 and Bob Jenkins, 2010.

I do not understand:

```c
bPowX[k+1] = (bPowX[k] >> 1) ^ P    // in Listing 1: Multiplication of normalized polynomials

//XpowN returns (x**N mod P(x))
result ^= Multiply(temp, Multiply(m, XpowN(d)));      // in Listing 2: Multiplication of unnormalized polynomial
```

Why do we need `^ P`?

Why do we need to calculate `mod P(x)`?

Comment: Questions about code are off-topic here.  Also, I can't understand what you are asking, or how it relates to the code.

Comment: @D.W. This question might be an exception to "questions about code are off-topic". The efficiency of CRC algorithms is fundamentally important. The expression of ideas in exact code is critical to the performance of CRC. It is reasonable to say that  pseudocode is not enough to explain CRC algorithms, unless they are basically the code themselves. The question here is asking how the "multiplication of D-normalized polynomials" is done in CRC.

Comment: People who are familiar with CRC should be able to answer this question easily.

Comment: Can folks who understand what is being asked edit the question to explain what is the question?  (For instance, I can't see any "XOR P" or any "mod P(x)" in the code.  I'm not sure what is meant by "why need" - I'm not sure what kind of answer is hoped for.)

Comment: I submitted an edit, but it needs to be approved by someone trusted, which apparently I am not.

Comment: @D.W. Let me welcome the first post of [the crc expert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Adler) on this site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question, the `>> 1` is multiplying the polynomial `bPowX[k]` by *x*. (The polynomials in this implementation are reflected, so the high powers of *x* are in the least significant bits.) The `^ P` is then taking that polynomial and computing the remainder upon dividing by the polynomial *P(x)*. That is the modulo operation, *mod P(x)*. The `^ P` is done only if multiplying by *x* results in a power of *x* that is the degree of *P(x)*, `D`. That happens when the low bit is initially a one, which represents *x<sup>D-1</sup>*. The `^` operation is how you subtract (or add for that matter) polynomials over GF(2).

For an analogy in integers, let's say I am doing my calculations modulo 13. I have 5 and double it, getting 10. Still less than 13, so it is already mod 13. That's like the branch in the polynomial code where the `& 1` is zero. I double it again and get 20. Now that's more than 13, so I need to subtract 13 to get 20 mod 13. That gives me 7. That's like the branch in the polynomial code where the `& 1` is one.

The second question is effectively: Why are we treating the *D* bits of a CRC as a polynomial over GF(2), and doing our operations modulo some polynomial over GF(2)? That is at the very core of the mathematics of cyclic redundancy checks, so the response would be too long for an answer here. There are many textbooks covering the use of finite fields for error detection and correction.